# Expected Value of the Ratio of Independent Variables, E(X/(X+Y))

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, expected-value, ratio

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, is the following true? Is there an easy way to show this?

$$E\left[\frac{X}{X+Y}\right]=\frac{E[X]}{E[{X+Y}]}=\frac{E[X]}{E[X]+E[Y]}$$

If this is not true in general, are there special cases when it is true (e.g. what $X$ and $Y$ are strictly positive and finite)?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is true if $X$ is independent of $1/(X+Y)$, and, hence, of $X+Y$. It is unlikely to happen unless $X$ is constant. Counterexample: $\mathbb{P}(X=0)=\mathbb{P}(X=1)=1/2$ and $Y=1$.

Comment: Even if you had that independence, $\mathsf E((X+Y)^{-1})$ is unlikely to equal $(\mathsf E(X+Y))^{-1}$

Comment: This holds for example when $X/(X+Y)$ is independent of $X+Y$ and the expectations exist (like when $X,Y$ are i.i.d Gamma variables).

Comment: @GrahamKemp Oops, yes this additional step completely skipped my mind. Thank you.